# Android: Can a webview automatically signin into an AppEngine app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, google-account

I did create a webapp on Google AppEngine, which requires Google Account SignIn.
I know Android has already a Google Account associated during registration.

Can I create an Android App consisting only of a webview, which automatically signs in to my webapp?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you get the authentication token from AccountManager for the "ah" (GAE) service (using ClientLogin, GAE still doesn't officially support OAuth2) and put it in the right header ("Auhtorization"), it should work. You will need to hook into your WebView in your code to do all those things, of course. Read documentation on Google authentication protocols for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with appEngine, but if you need the google account data to make whatever request you need, you can always use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)!